# conditions on using 'import' in a python program

Tags: python, function, import

I want to make a program (let's call it main.py) in which I want to execute a code written in some other file (call it xyz.py) and xyz.py uses variables say, a,b,etc. and I am giving the values of a and b in main.py. The program is not showing any error while running but it is not giving desired output. Let me illustrate by giving the following example.

#### main.py

```
a=float(input('Enter the initial guess: '))
print 'guesspoint:: '+`a`
method=input('Enter the method:: ')
print method
if method==1:
    print 'xyz'
    import xyz
else:
    print '123'
```

#### xyz.py

```
def wxyz(a):
    print 2*a
```

I have also tried using `from xyz import wxyz`, but I got the same output.

#### output

```
Enter the initial guess: 2.0
guesspoint:: 2.0
Enter the method:: 1
1
xyz
```

My actual code is for something else. I am just giving an example here. Please help me with this. My basic question is, do I need to define variables a,b,etc. in `xyz.py` also ?

Comment: You never actually *do anything* with the function you import from `xyz`, try adding `xyz.wxyz(a)` after `import xyz`. Also, all imports should be at the start of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you import the function in a module (`from xyz import wxyz`) then in your main code for `wxyz` function you must pass in its argument to print that ! like this :`wxyz(a)`

so your code must be like this :

```
from xyz import wxyz
a=float(input('Enter the initial guess: '))
print 'guesspoint:: '+ a
method=input('Enter the method:: ')
print method
if method=='1':
    wxyz(a)
else:
    print '123'
```

Comment: Your method comparison will fail because method is a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

**main.py**

```
from xyz import wxyz # <--- import function wxyz from `xyz.py`

a = float(input('Enter the initial guess: '))
print 'guesspoint:: ' + a
method = input('Enter the method:: ')
print method
if method == '1':
    wxyz(a)    # <--- Use function wxyz with local variable `a`
else:
    print '123'
```

Note that `method` is being received as a string.

Comment: you dont need `print` befor` wxyz(a) ` because after print `a` by function it print a `None` too by your print!